# O que significa o L, R, NC no HTACCESS?

Tags: apache, htaccess, servidor

Não entendi muito bem o funcionamento da flag `L`.

A dúvida surgiu quando eu estava tentando usar o seguinte script:

```
#quando vier o "public" na url, reescreve para folder/public
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ folder/public/$1 [NC]
Rewrite ^(.*)$ folder/public/$1 [NC]
```

Os objetivos era:

O primeiro:

`mysite.com` rescrever para `mysite.com/folder/public`.

O segundo (por conta de má estrutura do sistema desenvolvido):

`mysite.com/public/img.jpg` reescrever para `mysite.com/folder/public/img.jpg`

O segundo não estava funcionando. Porém, ao adicionar O `[NC,L]`, tudo funcionou como esperado.

Assim:

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ folder/public/$1 [NC]
Rewrite ^(.*)$ folder/public/$1 [NC]
```

O que o `L` fez na minha regra de reescrita?

O que significa as outras flags, como `R` e `NC`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Segue a [documentação](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) do Apache sobre as *flags*:

O `[L]` é *last*, ou seja, em uma lista de condições, não serão lidas as condições abaixo da que estiver com esta flag.

O `[R]` é *redirect*, isso comanda o navegador a fazer o redirecionamento. É preciso colocar a URL completa.

O `[NC]` é *no-case*, apenas faz com que as comparações sejam feitas no modo *case-insensitive*, ou seja, sem diferenciar maiúsculas de minúsculas.