# Como evitar redirecionamento de reescrita?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewrite

**Estou com a seguinte regra na raiz:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^webapp/(.*)$  ./sistema/public/v1/webapp/$1 [L,R=301]
```

O problema é que quando digito no navegador: http://projetoxyx.com.br/webapp

Ele está redirecionando e não reescrevendo para: http://projetoxyx.com.br/sistema/public/v1/webapp

**VHost:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@projetoxyx.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myuser/projects/projetoxyx"
    ServerName projetoxyx.local   
    ServerAlias www.projetoxyx.local
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-projetoxyz-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-projetoxyz-access.log" common

    setEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "/Users/myuser/projects/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Este é do sistema: ./sistema/public/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::^B$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]

    Options -Indexes
```

O que precisa fazer para ele não redirecionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove o `R=301`, essa flag afirma que é para fazer o redirecionamento 301 conforme a documentação https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r, mas se você só quer reescrever a url, remova-a assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^webapp/(.*)$ ./sistema/public/v1/webapp/$1 [L]
```

Eu não tenho certeza, mas creio que o `./` não esteja correto, se `sistema/` está na raiz o correto seria isso apenas:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^webapp/(.*)$ /sistema/public/v1/webapp/$1 [L]
```

Alguns detalhes nesta pergunta: [O que significa o L, R, NC no HTACCESS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55408/3635)